# What is the orthonormal basis of $L_2(R)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Since $L_2(\mathbb R)$ is separable, and it is a Hilbert space, then it must has a orthonormal basis. But how to get an orthonormal basis of it? In this case $sin(nx)$ and $cos(nx)$ do not converge, then how to construct an orthonormal basis? Thanks!

Comment: You should have a look at Hermite Polynomials

Comment: @nicomezi Thank you.

Comment: $1_{x\in [k,k+1)} e^{2i\pi nx}, k,n\in \Bbb{Z}$ works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose any diffeomorphism $\varphi :{\mathbb R}\to (0,2\pi )$ and define
$$
  T:L^2(0,2\pi )\to L^2(\mathbb R)
  $$
by
$$
  T(f)|_x = |\varphi '(x)|^{1/2}f(\varphi (x)),
  $$
for all $f$ in $ L^2(0,2\pi )$, and $x\in {\mathbb R}$.

Show that $T$ is a unitary
operator and then,  for any orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_n$ of $L^2(0,
2\pi )$, you get an orthonormal basis $\{T(e_n)\}_n$ for
$L^2({\mathbb R})$.